# How to do mysql rstrip

Tags: mysql

I have the following two values:

```
EN,
EN,FR
```

I want to change this to be as follows:

```
EN
EN,FR
```

How would I do the equivalent of:

```
str.rstrip(',')
```

in mysql?

Comment: The real solution is **not** to store multiple values in a single column.

Comment: @juergend right -- this is a group_concat operation.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't usually add trailing delimiters. You should fix whatever is adding them in the first place.

Comment: Try using `GROUP_CONCAT(NULLIF(columnname, ''))` so that empty strings are converted to `NULL`, and then they won't be included in the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `trim()` and specify exactly what (in this case `,`) and where (`TRAILING`, `LEADING` or `BOTH`):

```
  SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM 'EN,');
```